# mysql select where in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sub-query that works perfectly:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(zone SEPARATOR ', ') from typeofru where id in (5,7) /*This works good*/
```

The problem I have is the 5 and 7 are together on a varchar column ('5,7') and cannot make it works

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(zone SEPARATOR ', ') from typeofru where id in ('5,7') /*This is not working  */
```

How can I cast ('5,7') to a value type in order to make it works

The final query I need to use is this, but does not seems to work:

```
select name, (select GROUP_CONCAT(zone SEPARATOR ', ') from typeofru where id in (typeofru_ids)) from deviceru where device_id=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, '5,7') > 0
```

- [MYSQL FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> **Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings**. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, **the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic**.
>   **Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.**
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
>   properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

As a lesson to be learned, do not store values separated by a comma.

In the case that there are spaces before and after a comma, you need to replace the space first,

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, REPLACE(' 5 , 7', ' ','')) > 0
```